# Why can't I modify a vaadin components state after construction of UI?

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a vaadin UI, that has to be dynamic (visibility of fields should change based on user selections). I tried different ways of modifying components state like setEnabled(), setLabel(), ...

I have a ComboBox, in which the user selects values from en Enum. I added a ValueChangeListener to the ComboBox in which I try to modify Labels and other properties of some TextFields (setLabel(), setEnabled(), ...).

My ComboBox has a ValueChangeListener like this:

```
myComboBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> refreshLabels(event.getValue()));
```

First I wrote a method like this:

```
private void refreshLabels(MyEnum e){
   switch(e){
   case OPTION1: textField1.setLabel("some Text");
                 textField2.setLabel("some Text");
   case OPTION2: textField1.setLabel("some other Text");
                 textField2.setLabel("some other Text");
   }
}
```

**But with this method, the Labels will not be updated.**

Then I wrote another procedure for updating the Labels:

```
private String getNewLabel(MyEnum e){
   switch(e){
   case OPTION1: return "some Text";
   case OPTION2: return "some other Text";
   default: return "";
   }
}
```

I also chnaged the ValueChangeListener of my ComboBox:

```
myComboBox.addValueChangeListener(event -> textField1.setLabel(getNewLabel(event.getValue())));
```

**With this code, my labels are updated.**

As you see, I have a workaround but with this workaround, I have to write a getNeLabel method for every Field, because all fields will need different Labels when the ComboBox is updated. I do not understand, why my first approach does not work but the second one does. In both cases, the components are already added to a Layout and displayed on the UI, when the Label is changed. Can someone maybe explain this to me?

Comment: Are you using Push feature of the framework?

Comment: No, up to now I don't use it. I will try it this evening, but anyway I don't understand, why the two ways of modifying the labels above behave differently. I would expect both ways to work or not work, but I can't explain, why one is working and the other one not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is, actually, nothing wrong with your first approach and combobox should and **updates** values of textfields' labels correctly. The problem is in your snippet of code within a `switch` block. You forgot to add a `break;` there. Thus values are always set to the second(last) option, if there is *any* match. (In second case you are terminating execution of `switch` by returning from a method, therefore it works there)

From [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html):

> Each break statement terminates the enclosing switch statement. Control flow continues with the first statement following the switch block. The break statements are necessary because without them, statements in switch blocks fall through: All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.

This works for me correctly:

```java
 TextField textField1 = new TextField("first");
 TextField textField2 = new TextField("second");
//Some method here
 ComboBox<MyEnum> cb=new ComboBox<>();
 cb.setItems(MyEnum.values());
 cb.addValueChangeListener(event->{
        refreshLabels(event.getValue());
 });
 add(cb);
 add(textField1);
 add(textField2);
//End of a method here
 private void refreshLabels(MyEnum e){
             switch(e){
             case FIRST: textField1.setLabel("some Text");
                     textField2.setLabel("some Text");
                     break;
             case SECOND: textField1.setLabel("some other Text");
                     textField2.setLabel("some other Text");
                     break;
             }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you, of course that works! My other approach worked fine, because the return ended the switch statement. I can't believe that I did such a stupid mistake. Sorry for that :-)